# What does this warning (Your branch isn't protected) from GitHub mean?

Tags: git, github, security, repo

I have a warning on a particular GitHub repository that states:

> Your main branch isn't protected
>
> Protect this branch from force pushing or deletion, or require status
> checks before merging.

1. Does this mean that anyone can just delete my main branch?
2. Or, does this mean people in my "group" that have access in the first place are able to delete my main branch?  Thus, if I have no group of devs (I'm the only one) then the repo is protected by default?

**Is There Basic Protection?**

Isn't the repo protected by the fact that I have to sign in to push to it, meaning that someone would have to be able to sign in to the repo to delete or push against it?

Comment: @Caleb After reading about it I thought that was what it meant, but I couldn't confirm it. Thanks for your confirmation.  If you write it up as an answer I will mark it and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message means that contributors can force push and delete your branch. You would need to grant access to make someone a contributor.

Answer (score 0):

It means that anyone with write access to the repository can force push changes to the main branch, delete it or merge changes to the branch without passing through status checks. It is always advisable to protect your master branch. You can do this in the repository settings.